# What is the best way to code the customize search in django

Tags: python, django

I am using django for my application. I am new to it.
  I have the form where i multiple fields from where the user can perform search
  I have the relation hierarchy like Student has many subjects , then subjects has many assignments and assignements has many forms

I have divide the forms in  three sections where each section has 3-4 fields to search for e,g

```
 STUDENT DATA
  Name:
  StudentID
  city

  SUBJECTS DATA
  Start daTE
  NAME
  CREDITS

  ASSIGNEMENT DATA
  marks
  date_issue
  credits
```

I will be returning the list of students based on those seacrh criteria and they will be the partial matches.

I am new to django si i don't know how can i proceed with filtering of search because the search is also on nested objcets as well

I can perform one column search like

`Student.objects.filter(sbjects__icontains="math")`
but i don't know how can i simultaneously search for all

Can anyone give me the idea how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def your_view(request):
    students = Student.objects.filter()

    if request.GET.get('student'):
        students = students.filter(
            Q(name__contains=request.GET['student']) |
            Q(studentID__contains=request.GET['student']) |
            Q(city__contains=request.GET['student'])
            )

    if request.GET.get('subjects'):
        students = students.filter(
            Q(name__contains=request.GET['subjects']) |
            Q(credits__contains=request.GET['subjects'])
            )

    //more search here

    return render(request, 'page.html', {'students': students})
```

Comment: they all can be present simultaneously. also do i need request.POST or GET

Comment: request.GET because it is a search,

Comment: i really don't get what is GET['subjects'] , don't it be subjects_name  or something

Comment: I just make a sample based on the variable in your question, you didn't put your models code so I don't know the exact field name. You have the right to modified my codes

Comment: ok i get that now. I ahve one class based view where i have two methods one for showing the empty search form `def get` and other for showing the results `def post`. how can i sue request.GET in post function

Comment: but if i use that then how will `def post` method get called

Comment: `def post` is for saving and I don't know why you want to use that in searching

Comment: i am new to django so i thought i had to use that. how can i use def get to show the empty form and display the results as well

Comment: you have to create new question for that with your views

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that you are looking for `OR` query? Something like that:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Student.objects.filter( Q(subjects__icontains="math") | Q(name="John") )
```

The documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a loot at [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) plugin. It will allow you to make flattened indexes with model-like objects and then search very easy in them.

You can always go with Q objects and icontains lookups but it will be slow for relatively big amount of data.